# Размытие окна при клике и появление всплывающего окна

Tags: html, jquery, css, html5, css3

Подскажите код для реализации такого функционала:
1)Есть галерея из трех блоков (изображений и описания под ними);
2)Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на блок фон блока размывало;
3)И появлялось всплывающее окно с возможностью заказа.

Реализация подходит и с JQuery и с чистым CSS(если это возможно), заранее спасибо.

Comment: подсказываю: [фильтр размытия css](http://htmlbook.ru/css/filter/blur). по клику на нужный блок открываете поп-ап и добавляете это свойство тому блоку, который надо размыть

Comment: можно еще вопрос, а на сколько кроссбраузерное это решение ? 
"по клику на нужный блок открываете поп-ап и добавляете это свойство тому блоку, который надо размыть" - Это как ? не совсем понял

Comment: от того как вы будете открывать поп-ап зависит кроссбраузерность. можно через css, используя `div:target`, можно через js или jquery, используя событие `click`

Comment: спасибо за помощь

Comment: пример http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/fy8jn7x8/

Comment: только мне наоборот нужно, блоки с изображением уже есть, а чтобы нажимая на них изображение размывалось и выскакивало окно